# Jquery Gallery like Flash Gallery

Tags: jquery, html, gallery

I am trying to create a jquery image gallery like a flash gallery located on http://indiacarbonltd.com/core.html but I failed to create and I didn't find any close image galleries like the gallery located on the site I mentioned above by searching in the web.  Can anyone help me on that?

Comment: Why dont you use lightbox or fancybox. they do even better that the one in the link

Comment: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this Jquery plugins:

- **[Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/#inline2)**
- **[lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)**
- **[swipebox](http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/)**
- **[colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/)**

Comment: I have tried these but these are not being responsive.

Comment: go through this link..http://www.jqueryscript.net/lightbox/Responsive-jQuery-Lightbox-With-Amazing-CSS3-Effects-Fancy-Box-2.html and http://webdesignandsuch.com/posts/fancybox-download/fancyBox2/